# Is there any software to create doodles like doodlinator for windows 8?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need a software to create doodle animations just like the doodleinator in windows 8 which is very easy to use. Please give some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but you can give http://www.pencil-animation.org/ a try.

There are also other options in Ubuntu software center under "Graphics->Drawings"